# where can I set setVisibility gone to a textview in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and in each item I have a button. Sometimes I need to hide this button in some itens.

```
item 1
button visible

item 2
button gone
...
```

The problem is, I don't know where is the best place to set `MyButton` as `GONE`. I tried inside `public ViewHolder(View itemView)` but my app crashes.

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private final Context context;

    //List to store all posts
    List<Posts> Posts;


    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<Posts> Post, Context context){
        super();
        this.Posts = Post;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.posts_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Posts post =  Posts.get(position);
        holder.post = post;

        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(post.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(post.getName());
        holder.textViewPublisher.setText(post.getPublisher());
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewPublisher;
        public TextView textViewMyButton;
        public Posts post;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
            textViewMyButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMyButton);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //
        }

    }
}
```

I want to do something like that:

`if(StringName == "1"){
 TextView txtView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MyButton);
                                    txtView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}`

any ideas where and how can I add this to hide buttons in recyclerview where StringName==1?

Comment: 1) you're comparing strings wrong 2) show the code that crashes and the error associated with it

Comment: This is bothering me, by the way, but your `Posts` class is a singular object representing one post, so naming it `Post` would make more sense ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Posts post =  Posts.get(position);
        holder.post = post;

        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(post.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        if(condition is true){

        holder.textViewName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
        holder.textViewName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
            holder.textViewName.setText(post.getName());

  holder.textViewPublisher.setText(post.getPublisher());
            holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        }
```

You can set visibility in `onBindViewHolder` like above.
You have to set both visibilities to your view.If you only set it to gone and do not write it to become visible when condition is true.You will encounter errors while scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

The best place would be `onBindViewHolder` because you have access to the current row of the adapter and any data that'll be displayed there.

You shouldn't use the constructor of the ViewHolder because that should simply "hold views".

If your app crashes, we need more information than you provided

Answer (score 1):

You should set the visibility inside the `OnBindViewHolder` method.
And checking String in Java should not use "==" as in `StringName == "1"`
and should use "equals" instead like `StringName.equals("1")`

Comment: oh, thank you very much. I'm a php developer and thought it was the same here.